# Change the font size of a UITextField in a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uialertview

Does anyone know how to change the font size of a UITextField within a UIAlertView? The following is my code...

```
- (void) editTitle
{
    NSString *string = kLocalizedString(@"Edit Title");

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                message:string
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    if (!self.title) {
        textField.text = nil;
    }
    else {
        textField.text = self.title;
    }

    textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    textField.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;

    // These statements have no effect on the size of the text field's font
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]}; 
    textField.typingAttributes = attributes;

    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Hi just here to say that I up-voted your question, since a user has dow-nvoted it without giving any sort of explanation. Down-vote should be allowed only with an explanation.

Comment: You are using a default UIAlertView, not a custom. I think you can't do this.

Comment: Prior to ios7, you can do, but after this you can't. However you can create your own custom view similar to UIAlertView and do whatever changes you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After iOS 7.x you cannot customize the appearance of alert views,

### Why?

Because its view hierarchy is private.

It is mentioned clearly in [UIAlertView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   **must not be modified**.

So unfortunately it is impossible to change the textField font, buttons text color .. etc.

The only solution is using one of the custom UIAlertView's.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use custom alertview. Just check below link.

### [DTAlertView](https://github.com/Darktt/DTAlertView)

It has good animation and textfield can be added too.

Once you use this, you don't have to write such big code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `UIAlertView` using one of this:

1. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics--mobile-8886
2. https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog

and apply your custom `textField`.

For the second option, in **CODialog.m** (`addTextFieldWithPlaceholder` function) you can change the font size, or modify `kCODialogTextFieldHeight` constant.

```
field.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kCODialogTextFieldHeight - 8.0];
```